# Google Cloud - Wrong project id being used from different email address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Despite running `gcloud auth application-default login` and `gcloud config set core/project CORRECT_PROJECT_ID` the project keeps defaulting to an incorrect project id:

```
gcloud config list
[core]
account = CORRECT_EMAIL
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = CORRECT_PROJECT_ID

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

I can successfully run the sample code from the tutorial (below) if I run in the terminal
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"

However, I didn't want to have to do this every time, so I ran the command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

This opened a browser with a list of my gmail accounts, and even though I selected the correct account, the success window went to a different gmail account. So then I tried it in an incognito window, and it worked.

However, running npm start resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR: { Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Natural Language API has not been used in project WRONG_PROJECT_ID before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/language.googleapis.com/overview?project=WRONG_PROJECT_ID then retry.
```

Then I ran `gcloud config set core/project CORRECT_PROJECT_ID` and got the message `Updated property [core/project].`

When I run npm start I get the same message:

```
ERROR: { Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Natural Language API has not been used in project WRONG_PROJECT_ID before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/language.googleapis.com/overview?project=WRONG_PROJECT_ID then retry.
```

I tried `gcloud auth login` and got the following message (after I authenticated in an incognito window):

```
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help

You are now logged in as [CORRECT EMAIL ADDRESS].
Your current project is [CORRECT_PROJECT_ID].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 8):

I have a few suggestions that may correct this behaviour.

1) Clear your web browser cache & cookies. Then run "gcloud auth application-default login"

2) Try re-installing the gcloud toolkit.

3) Try [unsetting](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/unset) the project in your config first, then set the project to the correct project. i.e.

```
gcloud config unset project WRONG_PROJECT_ID
gcloud config set project CORRECT_PROJECT_ID
```

4) Check the [“CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT”](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/) environment variable. Set it to the correct project if it is not already.

5) Try re-running [“gcloud init”](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init)

6) You can find your application default credentials in

> Linux: ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
>
> Windows: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\credentials

You can delete the file, & regenerate it using commands you had mentioned in your question such as “gcloud auth default-credentials login”

We need to find where npm start is getting its credentials from. Once we figure that out, we can figure out how to change it, & understand why it’s looking there etc.

Are you able to find the config file to see where it is looking for credentials?
Is npm start the entire command? I’m not too familiar with Node JS. I’m not sure why it is trying to use Natural Language API.
You also mentioned a tutorial but I think you may have forgotten to include it in your question. Which tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: this worked, but I did steps 3 then 1 in that order and stop

Comment: holy john wyane! I thought I had gone through everything but I had not removed application_default_credentials.json Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

****TLDR; Check IAM permissions for your service account, and the permission(s) you need to perform the activity you wish.****

You may be using the correct service account, however the permissions for the service account may not allow the API you're trying to access via the account.

I had this issue, trying to read a secret. Trying some different calls from the `@google-cloud/secret-manager` node module lead me to realize it was only accessing the secret that was failing.

Editing the access in IAM solved the issue. So the error message seems spurious, in my case anyway.