# How Do You Get a Discord Bot That Uses The Translation API And Requires a Powershell Command At Each Initiation onto a Server?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js, google-translation-api

I'm creating a Discord bot and I've decided to use the Google Translation API to make the bot translate text between different languages on request.

However, at each initiation of the bot, I am required to run a Powershell command for the Discord bot to have the Translation feature enabled. Without, the command does not work.

The command is as follows: `$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"`

This points the bot to the Service Key for the Google Translate API Project.

Full documentation here: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs)

This would work perfectly if I intended to only run it on my machine, but I want to run it 24/7 on a server, and I have Heroku already set up.

How would I go about setting this up on a server, because at the moment, I have no clue.

All help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The command you're using is to declare an environment variable.

**Node.js**
You can do it as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005448/setting-up-environment-variables-in-node-specifically-google-application-crede#answer-55036716):

```js
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/absolute/path/to/key.json" node index.js
```

**Heroku**
You can also set the env var directly on Heroku ([documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)):

```js
heroku config:set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/absolute/path/to/key.json
```

**Docker**
Alternatively, you can create a Docker image or build it with Heroku and set the env variables in Docker.

[Heroku Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) and [Docker env file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) / [Docker compose env var](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: Although the links provided may answer the question, it's best to extract the important parts and reference the links. If the URLs become invalid, a portion of this answer will no longer be helpful.

Comment: @slothiful I agree. But I didn't develop Docker becaus it the way it will be used will depend on how you'll use Docker. Moreover I mentionned Docker because it can help with the problem, but also because it could be something nice to use. I would have detailled all the way to set env var / solve the problem with Docker if the question was about Docker / OP mentionned he use it. But again I agree. Do you think more detail are needed about the node or heroku part?

Comment: In my opinion there's enough details already to hopefully help future readers. As long as your answer isn't just one link saying "see here," it's generally okay.

Comment: Hi, I've used your second method with Heroku and got the bot to actually not crash at startup. However, now, the bot will always throw an error when trying to startup. The bot works, but even if the language code is valid, it throws an error in the Discord channel it is in. "Invalid language code! Languages codes are at https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages !" I've checked the code and it is the exact same as the version I have on my local machine. Why is this?

Comment: @MoneyHurricane Well this is a google-translate error. I advice you to open another question and give maybe more detail (What is the line that produce the error? What are the step to reproduce? etc)

Comment: Looking into the Heroku logs, it seems like just linking the absolute path does not work. ```2019-06-28T15:20:59.275085+00:00 app[worker.1]: ERROR { Error: The file at C:\Users\Name\Documents\epic-bot\File Name.json does not exist, or it is not a file. ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/app/C:\Users\Name\Documents\epic-bot\File Name.json'
[various error jargon]
2019-06-28T15:20:59.275153+00:00 app[worker.1]: path:
2019-06-28T15:20:59.275155+00:00 app[worker.1]: '/app/C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\epic-bot\\File Name.json' }```

Comment: @MoneyHurricane are you sure it's the heroku absolute path? (I don't know heroku at all). But `/app/C:... ` doesn't seems to be a correct absolute path.

Comment: I know this probably sounds really stupid (I'm still learning) but I don't know what the absolute path would be for an online service. I'll look into it though.

Comment: @MoneyHurricane it's not necessarily for an online service. It's seems to be an Unix system. And it append the `/app` at the start. Maybe the bot is situed in `/app`. Try to replace your path by the name of the file alone. Just for info, `<Name>:\ ` is a windows path (name being usually a letter. Unix have `/` instead of `\ ` and an absolute path start with `/`